# Is it possible to transfer individual page facebook likes to website facebook likes

Tags: facebook

I would like to know if it is possible to transfer individual page likes , eg. we have a website `www.example.com/mobiles/nokia/mobilname.php` this page has 256 likes , and our website `www.example.com` has 5000 likes. I want to transfer those above 256 likes to the website likes so that I can get 5256 likes. Is it possible to do this in Facebook.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope - you can't do that.  It is impossible to move "likes" from pages to websites, from websites to pages, from pages to pages or any other combination you can think of.

If someone "likes" a page - how do you know that he "likes" your URL?  Simple answer - you don't.