# Transferring website likes to fanpage likes

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

as far as I understood Facebook also offers "likes" for plain websites without their own fanpage.

Now, if one has a certain number of such likes and decides to open a dedicated fanpage is there a way to transfer respectively migrate these "likes" to the fanpage or does he have to start from zero?

Answer (score 1):

No there isn't. The "likes" are per page/website and are non transferable.

Comment: Thats what I assumed but I thought there might be a migration if one first only had plain likes and then opens for the very same URL a page. But from your reply I take there is no such feature, right? Probably the best to go with a fanpage.

Comment: [It doesn't the other way either](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11451781/is-it-possible-to-transfer-individual-page-facebook-likes-to-website-facebook-li/11451887#11451887)

Comment: @user1669663 - no problem! :)  Don't forget to use [comment replies](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) so that users will get notifications on your comments.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the Migration document here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/migration/

There's deprecated functionality, due for removal soon, where liking a URL as the admin defined in that page's Open Graph meta tags resulted in an 'Open Graph page', similar to a regular Facebook Page, being created.

There's a migration option available now which will create a regular Facebook page and migrate the fans across to the new page, details of which are on that document. I believe it's as simple as enabling the migration option in the app settings and navigating to the admin interface for the Open Graph page where a button will be present to start the migration

Comment: Thanks a million Igy. Although I have to admit I understand about 10%. What is an admin page? And what exactly is due to be removed? Are you saying currently a migration is possible but that functionality is removed soon? The basic idea behind my question is to have first only a plain website like button and latter should the need arise create a fanpage and naturally I would like to keep the existing likes.

Comment: That's a migration of the Like-Button *functionality* - not a migration of "likes"

Comment: @alfasin Well, the functionality is handled on Facebook's end. What does the enduser need to migrate here? And how would it relate to a possible like migration?

Comment: alfasin - the people who are fans of the URL with the open graph page should remain fans of the page you migrate that URL to

Comment: @user1669663 - currently, when you have a like button on your site, there's a sort of virtual  'admin' facebook page associated with that URL - this is being removed. as part of the removal of that functionality, existing URLs with an admin page have the option to convert to a regular page and maintain the likes